# Need suggestions for capturing digital signature in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I'm creating a Salesforce App that requires Digital Signature from customer as attachment.  Following is the flow of the process..

a) Send a form to customer for capturing signature. For capturing signature from customer, I prefer [**Signature Pad**](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) by Thomas Bradly

b) Send a link to customer's email to capture signature outside salesforce. (Is there any way to do it inside salesforce?)

c)Customer signs and saved the same in some database.

d)Update the signature in Salesforce account.

Am I missing something? How can I make it more secure? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can capture the signature in salesforce.com using a Force.com site (a Visualforce page that requires no authentication). Simply build a Visualforce page using Signature Pad (I actually wrote my own custom version once just for kicks, took me about 30-45 minutes), create a site with your page enabled, and then include a link to the site via email. The site could use authentication as an additional layer of security, if you're willing to pay for a High Volume Portal License ("cost effective", yet still expensive for small businesses), or you could just send them a link that encludes encrypted URL parameters, possibly as one-time use links (e.g. soon as they sign, it prevents that token from ever being used again). Salesforce.com easily has the technology to allow you to secure capture signatures entirely within salesforce.com, including sending the email, capturing the data, etc.

Comment: Gr8! Thanks for the sharing your work.

Comment: Amazing work.Thanks sfdcfox Saved a lot of time :)

Answer (score 4):

A good suggestion would be to look at using [Docusign](http://www.docusign.com/) or [Echosign](https://www.echosign.adobe.com/en/home.html) as they offer great security and simple configuration that is widely used by many Salesforce customers.

Comment: Although I'm slightly biased (I work for https://signrequest.com) I think they offer a flexible and affordable alternative worth checking out.